# Shutdown Windows after set number of invalid login attempts

Tags: windows, login

I want my full-disc encrypted Windows to automatically shut itself down (preferably hibernation mode instead of a complete shutdown to prevent data loss) after 3 invalid login attempts so the hypothetical intruder may enjoy the beautifully designed VeraCrypt bootloader. ;)

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Configure Windows to log failed logon attempts. Write a script to monitor the security event log for failed logon attempts and shut down the system after 3 such attempts. But wouldn't it be better to prevent the intruder from being able to get as far as the logon screen in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this program, but [Smart PC Locker Pro](http://www.novirusthanks.org/products/smart-pc-locker-pro/) has this functionality.

You could do some scripting to do it... but why reinvent the wheel?